# PostgreSQL over SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, postgresql, ssh-tunnel

### The Goal

What I want to do is accessing a remote PostgreSQL database over SSL.

### The problem

The database serverhas no own certificate.

### The whole picture

We have two different servers which run versions of the same webapp.

The first (let's call it `Fizz`) has a SSL certificate, runs nginx and the webapp is accessible (only) via HTTPS.

The second one (`Buzz`) has no SSL certificate.
To provide a somehow secure connection the webapp is accessible only over `Fizz`'s SSL connection.
For this to work `Fizz`'s nginx is configured to proxy `Buzz`'s webapp through it's own SSL connection.
HTTP(S) connections from other machines are refused by `Buzz`.

This means https://fizz/A shows `Fizz`'s webapp and https://fizz/B shows `Buzz`'s.

This works fine.

But now we need secure access to the (postgres) database running on `Buzz`.

Since we have on top of all a company firewall running I can't access it directly, but it works over SSH tunneling.

If I want access via SSL I have to access it via the `Fizz`. And I don't know how.
I hoped I could configure nginx to do something similar to what is does to the webapps.

Is this even possible? I'm not sure how to configure that.
All information I find on the net refer to http and webserver.

Or is there some other way, maybe SSH/SSL tunnel to `Fizz` and redirect the traffic to `Buzz`?

I'm a little lost.

### Edit 2016-09-22

I made a picture to make the situation a little more clear (hopefully):
[image: Diagram]
The green path is what is working. I can access `Fizz` over https and nginx establishes the connection to `Buzz` which delivers the webapp.

The orange path is what I'd like to do. Basically the same thing, but not with a website, but with a database connection.

And I'm not sure if it is possible with nginx.

### Edit 2016-09-23

Based on Tims link I now set this up:

The SSH tunnel to get around the proxy:

`5443:localhost:5443`

as well as a nginx rule:

```
stream {
    listen 5443 ssl;
    proxy_pass buzz:5432
}
```

The idea:

- establish an ssh connection to Fizz
- open a tunnel 5443:localhost:5443
- let the client connect to localhost:5443
- let nginx listen to 5443 and
- redirect it to Buzz:5432

which is the port the database listens to.

Testing the connection with `ncat` returns
`Close: Result too large`

So I'm not sure, until where the connection works.

Comment: Your question is really unclear and difficult to follow. If you want to add SSL to a server just buy or otherwise procure a certificate (eg free with Let's Encrypt), install it, and configure it to be used by applicable software.

Comment: @Tim: I'm sorry, the question is unclear. But it is a rather strange configuration. I guess if it is necessary, my company will buy a new certificate. But for now my task is to try it this way.

Comment: konch - would a concise problem statement be "I would like to give public access to a PostgreSQL database via an Nginx proxy running on port 443"? Would this be a tunnel or would you change the default listen port of 5432? Or would you like Nginx to listen on port 5432? If so this probably answers your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545648/tcp-proxy-to-postgres-database-as-an-upstream-server-in-nginx

Comment: @Tim: That seems to be related. I've tried using streams to redirect the incoming connection, but I'm not sure if my connection gets through, though. Using `ncat` to test the connection I get a
`close: Result too large`
pgAdmin refuses a connection with "server closed the connection unexpectedly".